# Cross Domain Scripting using Rest-Angular and rails

Tags: angularjs, cors, restangular

I am building an application using Rest-Angular and Rails. Angular is running on localhost:9000 where as Rails on 3000. Due to some cross domain issues, i am not able to send POST request. I have already tried these things before posting :

1.) Used a rails gem to change the url as below

```
 config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins 'localhost:9000'
      resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options, :delete]
    end
   end
```

2.) Change in request headers

```
baseAccounts.post(newAccount,{},{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'accept,content-type,X-Token,programDigest'});
```

I am able to send GET request, but somehow POST is still not working.

Headers for my last try

```
Request URL:http://0.0.0.0:3000/singup
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept,content-type,X-Token,programDigest
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Request Payloadview parsed
{"first_name":"Rajan","last_name":"Chaudhary","email":"dfgd@fgfd.com"}
```

and the error was

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://0.0.0.0:3000/singup. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: why is your angular page not being served from your rails server to avoid this completely?

Comment: i want to host the 2 pieces on different server

Answer (score 2):

This is called Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing and it's a method to allow the sharing of data across different url origins (unsurprisingly). Browsers implement protection to stop cross-site-scripting (XSS) and this is the issue you're currently running into. More information can be found here: http://enable-cors.org

You're close to getting it to work. It's the server that needs to respond with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header so that it will work.

Specifically each resource (every endpoint) needs to accept an `OPTIONS` request which responds with `200 OK` and the following response headers (instead of allowing all methods you can specify only some allowed methods for a resource, for example `GET` only).

- Minimum: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
- Methods: `Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS`

Further information [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

It's probably worth noting that this actually circumvents the whole point of the Cross Origin Resource Sharing protection that the browser and Angular are providing. Deployment sites should specify the exact allowed origin instead of `*`.